# ActiveSheet.Paste Failing VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, paste

My VBA code is set to copy a value from one sheet (NB this value will change each time the sheet is open) and paste into a 'database' on the next available row.

Think I've got it right but the Paste method seems to fail, can anyone see why?

```
Windows("Invoice Program.xlsm").Activate
Range("B4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Invoice Database.xlsx")
Windows("Invoice Database.xlsx").Activate
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Selection.Paste
```

Comment: Please see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683)

Comment: What do you mean "fail"?  Do you get an error?  Does the value not change?

Comment: Yes sorry I get error 438, edited now to use Selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim varTemp as Variant

Windows("Invoice Program.xlsm").Activate
Range("B4").Select
varTemp = ActiveCell.Value
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Invoice Database.xlsx")
Windows("Invoice Database.xlsx").Activate
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
ActiveCell = varTemp
```

Comment: Hey, cheers for the help but ActiveSheet is what I had originially,i get 'Paste method of Worksheet class failed' error 1004

Comment: I used some "dummy" workbooks on my system and the code ran fine.  Is it the last line of code that creates the error message?

Comment: Yeah ActiveSheet.Paste is what flags up as the error

Comment: I edited the code to use a variant variable instead of using the clipboard.  Maybe this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use ActiveSheet.Paste but in the line before use DoEvents.

```
DoEvents
ActiveSheet.Paste
```